# When should prefer angular directive over html native tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a big fan of angularjs, I started lately to use it in all of my '*coding for fun*' projects.
I have a big curiosity:

I have a two inputs, one disabled by a **ng-disabled** directive and the other disabled with an **html tag** (A better illustration in this [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/JvJuSrxYrtgPoj15SxeI?p=preview)):

```
//...

<input type="text" disabled value="This is an html input text disabled" />
<input type="text" ng-disabled="true" value="disabled with angular js directive" />

//...
```

Using the browser ability I can right click on the input and remove the disabled and ng-disabled tags but only the one with the disabled tag would be editable, the other one will still be tracked by angular even when ng-disabled directives has been removed.

So, When and Why should I prefer using ng directives over native html tags? Which could be the impact of letting angular track all these actions? is it really worth to use it everywhere?

Comment: Prefer directives when you want live data-binding between your model and your view. Otherwise, use native HTML attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the native html 'disabled' if the element should always be disabled. (static, for example if you want to provide an input with text and never let the user change it)
Use angular if it should change based on variables value in the scope.

For example, say a button should change the state of an input.

```
<input type="button" ng-click="inpDisabled = true" >Disable Input</input>
<input type="text" ng-disabled="inpDisabled" />
```

[live example](http://jsbin.com/neqim/1/edit?html,js,output)

No harm will come if you still use `ng-disabled="true"` but it's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make directive static, you shoud use native html

```
<your-tag disable><your-tag>
```

against

```
<your-tag ng-disabled="true"><your-tag>
```

But AngularJS does not work this way, you shoud initialize your application and controller, then pass a variable as parameter to your directive:

**JS:**

```
$scope.isDisabled = true;
```

**HTML:**

```
<your-tag ng-disabled="isDisabled"><your-tag>
```

You shoud read more tutorials to make things clear